# GUI apps script, returning "undefined " value

Tags: google-apps-script, gui-builder

i've created simple GUI with a flow panel name and ID `main panel`, a label name `Label1` a textbox name `myTextBox` and a button with ID `getETA`.

my aim is if i enter a value in text box and click submit den the value should write in spreadsheet.
my problem is the script is returning undefined in spreadsheet not the actual value i've entered.

```
var app = UiApp.createApplication();
app.setTitle("My Application");
app.add(app.loadComponent("MyGui"));
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().show(app);
var clickHandler = app.createServerHandler('clickGetETA');
clickHandler.addCallbackElement(app.getElementById('mainPanel'));
app.getElementById('getETA').addClickHandler(clickHandler);
var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
doc.show(app);

}

 // this function responds to submit button
function clickGetETA(e) {
var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
var textBoxValue = e.parameter.myTextBox;
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow()+1;
var lastCell = sheet.getRange("A"+lastRow);
lastCell.setValue(textBoxValue);
return app.close();

}
```

I'm new to stackoverflow dont have enough reputations to post image so posting links of images

[image1](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4SXyUxVTGRBczhtc21RdjNnOGc/edit)
 [image2](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4SXyUxVTGRBczhtc21RdjNnOGc/edit)
 [image3](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4SXyUxVTGRBZ2Y2Y01XWHZ3Z0U/edit)
 [image4](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4SXyUxVTGRBSExIcHBCd3JsV28/edit)
 [image5](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4SXyUxVTGRBbEtTd3RpSDhVMTg/edit)
 [image6](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4SXyUxVTGRBaFBDU1Fqam9YbmM/edit)
 [image7](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4SXyUxVTGRBNjU3TnQ0b0MxZ28/edit)

Comment: I converted your links to 'real links' for comfort ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you defined the clickHandler in the script **AND** in the GUI builder... that is one too much, that's probably the cause of the issue

Please try to remove the one in the GUI builder and test again, I don't see any other problem in your test ;-)

You could also of course remove the handler in the script but in that case you should add the callbackelement in there too by developing the smal '+' near the handler name and put your panel there.

EDIT : Sorry, there are 2 handlers in the GUI builder, so that is **two** too much ! you cannot use a single handler with a single name on 2 different handler type (click & key) if you want to have multiple handlers on a button you should define as many handlers you need, each of the type you want, eventually calling the same function but with different variable names.

Edit 2 the line `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().show(app);` in the begining of the main function souldn't be there either, just remove it since you call the spreadsheet later with `var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();`

Working code with GUI [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AnqSFd3iikE3dHkyMkhYY01iV19nUm0zaGJwUEg2X0E)

**EDIT 3  : issue solved** by sharing the questioner sheet, the panel name was not correctly written : `mainPanel` in the script and `mainpanel` in the GUI ... 
Aaaah, case sensitiveness ! ;-)  (visible in image6)

Comment: ... i've removed key handler in GUI and tried still the problem remain same ....returning undefined value...

Comment: did you remove both handlers in the GUI builder ?

Comment: no i removed only key handler , do u want me to remove click handler as well?

Comment: i've also removed click handler in GUI and tried ... but the problem remain same..

Comment: I reproduced your test and it works, see link   https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AnqSFd3iikE3dHkyMkhYY01iV19nUm0zaGJwUEg2X0E

Comment: yes i've checked ur script its working... but mine is still not working....cant figure it out where i going wrong ... https://docs.google.com/a/kezo.in/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AsS9MOupoFlJdHBuYS1YRGtIVG1pd1ROSDZDaGYtc1E#gid=0

Comment: got worked ...thank q 4 help ... i had assigned GUI id for panel as mainpanel n in script as mainPanel...serge insas..corrected it.. and got work..